# Cosa sono i "serracchi"?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Così, per delega di tutti, come lo sorpresi solo,
>   una mattina sul tardi, e miracolosamente arrendevole, m’impadronii del suo braccio e m’indirizzai verso l’angolo meno educato del parco, dove pruni selvatici e ciuffi di **serracchi** avevano straripato sul viale, scoraggiando i passi ma promettendo, se non comodo, solitudine.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa sono i "serracchi"? Ho cercato "serracchio" e "serracco" su parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questi vocaboli.

Comment: Il testo fa pensare ad una pianta o meglio un cespuglio selvatico. Credo sia una grafia diversa per indicare il saracchio 
http://hoincontroalbero.blogspot.it/2012/10/saracchio.html

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Secondo me potresti scriverlo come risposta.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Sono d'accordo con Denis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il testo citato fa pensare ad una pianta o meglio un cespuglio selvatico.

Credo sia una grafia diversa (forse dialettale) per indicare il saracchio, che è una pianta tipica della vegetazione mediterranea.

http://hoincontroalbero.blogspot.it/2012/10/saracchio.html

Da notare che secondo [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampelodesmos_mauritanicus) in Toscana la pianta viene chiamata *sarracchio*